# GNU makefile. execute some statements by condition

Tags: linux, makefile, embedded, gnu-make

i need to execute some action depending on some condition. i use the following:

```
ifeq($(somevar),1)
$(call target,etc/init.d/tr): ${SRCPATH}/init.d
        install -D --mode=755 $< $@
endif
```

and here i'm getting the error:

```
/BRCMakefile:38: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

Where 38 is the line number where my ifeq is located. 
Can't find out what i'm missing. 
Can u help w/ this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work `ifeq "$(somevar)" '1'`